# Windows userprofile folder showing different items depending on how it's accessed

Tags: windows-10, registry

I was recently cleaning up my %USERPROFILE% folder, this included deleting the *documents* and *pictures* folders from the OneDrive folder, changing some registry entries, etc.

However, Now when I go to my userprofile folder via the pinned link in Quick Access I do not see my Documents folder, but when I got to the userprofile folder through C:\Users\user it is there. If I type C:\Users\Username\Documents in search, I also reach the right folder.

The problem persists after refreshes of file explorer and after restarts.

**Image of folder through quick access shortcut**
[image: Image of folder through quick access shortcut]

**Image of folder through manual navigation**
[image: Image of folder through manual navigation]

**Image of registry keys I edited**
[image: Image of registry keys I edited]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by deleting some other registry values pointing to (the non-existent) %USERPROFILE%/OneDrive in:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell
  Folders